# How to pass a Bitmap object between the two Activity instances?

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmap

How to pass a `Bitmap` object between the two `Activity` instances?

Answer (score 2):

Bitmap implements Parcelable, so you could always pass it in the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourNewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and retrieve it on the other end

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Comment: I feel that doing so is not a very good method.May you use the static Bitmap.

Comment: Static bitmap is worst than to put it in the intent. The intent is the cleanest way.

Comment: I agree, I don't see why it's not a good method, it's standard Android practice. Maybe if you tell us more about what you're doing or post some code then we can make better suggestions.

Comment: Just getting started with Android development, not too much to understand, a lot of advice.